# How to break a JS script in case of too long execution time?

Tags: node.js, infinite-loop

I have a Node.js script, which uses some external library. The problem is with this function it freezes (probably some infinite loop inside) for a specific arguments. Example code:

```
const Elemenets = [/*...*/];
for(let i=0 ; i < Elements.length ; i++) {
   console.log(`Running ${i}/${Elements.length} ...`);
   someExternalFunction(Elements[i]);
}
```

My console:

```
Running 1/352 ...
Running 2/352 ...
Running 3/352 ...
Running 4/352 ...
Running 5/352 ...
Running 6/352 ...
// the script freezees here
```

Is there any way to do something like:

> if **someExternalFunction** takes longer than 10 seconds, break it and continue the loop

If the function cannot work properly for some arguments I can handle it. But I don't want one damaged element to freeze the entire loop.
If there is no possibility to solve it this way, maybe there is some another approach to this problem?
Thanks

Comment: what does the array look like you're looping through and what does it look like when you pass it the function `someExternalFunction`.  If you comment out  `someExternalFunction` does it loop correctly? You also state is freezes on some arguments, whats different about those then others?

Comment: I think what you say might be possible with a multithreaded language bu with js I don't think so. If yuor process is stuck in a function you will not be able to do anything before it breaks.
So if you don't have hand on the implementation of that external function, I suggest not to use it, or maybe avoid the problematic argument...

Comment: @Peterrabbit the problem is I don't know which argument will be problematic before the function freezees on it. But it always freezees on the same arguments.

Comment: @Przemek Could you provide more details about the implementation of `SomeExternalFunction` ? It could be useful to understand how it is written and why it behaves like this..

Comment: It's a **Bitmap.resize()** method from the **imagejs** library. But I`m wondering if there is any "high level" solution, to solve this problem without going into the implementation of external libraries.

Comment: I think the only way to kill an infinite loop is at browser level because it has access to other available threads and can stop the js process. Bu if js is stuck it's stuck... I don't think there's a way to unstock it from the stuck process. That's why I better suggest to find the reason of the bug and not to get stuck.

Comment: Or maybe report the bug to the maintainer of the lib (if the bug is from that function..)